# Adding identity values to existing column based on data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has the following data arrangement:

[image]

In this table, existing_order is the order in which the table is intentionally designed to be. However, because of the inconsistency, I want to add one more column as 'Line No' that is like an identity column that starts newly for every CID number.I want the resultant data to be as below:

[image]

I can create a quick work around in fiddler and share it soon. Any help will be appreciated!

Rextester link: http://rextester.com/live/TWO92019

Comment: Identities don't work the way you mentions here. It won't "reset" based on values from another column, nor it will keep different seeds. You option would be manually setting the ranking and keeping it updated via trigger, but it seems that this value is best calculated on demand rather than stored (unless you have other business processes that needs it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()` function :

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by CID, PDI order by Agent) as LineNo
from table t;
```

However, i don't relay on `PDI` so, you can remove it from `partition` clause if needed.

Comment: I want to edit table structure to add this column. Not just select query

Comment: @Rick. . . Then alter table structure add `LineNo` column with `null` constraint and use the `update` statement. You are in touch way.